# How to fix NIS with error code (1) (sudo apt-get purge nis)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nis

When I first time installed NIS, it came out with a "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" problem.

So I removed NIS with "sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/nis.*" command.
then reinstalled with "sudo apt-get purge nis" command.
but it still got this problem "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)".
How to fix it? Need help!